# Looping through 'tablelayout' to return specific button tag

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to loop through a table layout in order to find a button with a specific tag, set it as a variable and return it.
The problem I have is that in the loop I am moving through views and then returning a view and trying to set it as a button.
I tried changing some of the `view` variables to `Button` but can't quite seem to get it to work.
Specific method in question here is `aiPlayerPick` returning object to `playerClick`.

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.connect3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public boolean noughtsTurn;
    ArrayList board;
    Players player;
    String aiPickedButton;

    public void receiveClick(View view) {
        String buttonPressed = (String) view.getTag();
        board.remove(buttonPressed);
        System.out.println(board);
        humanPlayerTurn(view);
        aiPlayerTurn(view);
    }

    public void humanPlayerTurn(View view) {
        playerClick(view);
        noughtsTurn = !noughtsTurn;
    }
   public void aiPlayerTurn(View view) {
       aiPickedButton = randomButtonPick();
       playerClick(view);
       noughtsTurn = !noughtsTurn;
   }

    public void playerClick(View view) {
        if (view instanceof Button) {
            Button B = (Button) view;
            if ( noughtsTurn ) {
                B.setText(player.noughtsPlayer());
            } else {
                Button A = (Button) aiPlayerPick();
                A.setText(player.crossesPlayer());
            }
            B.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public String randomButtonPick() {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        String randomBoardNumber = String.valueOf(randomNumber.nextInt(board.size()));
        return randomBoardNumber;
    }

    public View aiPlayerPick() {
        View a = null;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i));
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getTag() == aiPickedButton) {
                        a = view;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public class Players {
        public String noughtsPlayer() { return "O"; }
        public String crossesPlayer() { return "X"; }
        public String blankButton() { return ""; }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        boolean noughtsTurn = true;
        board = new ArrayList();
        for (int x = 0; x < getBoardSize(); x++) {
            String y = String.valueOf(x);
            board.add(y);
        }
        player = new Players();

    }

    public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button) {
                        buttonCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return buttonCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="#070000">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton1"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="0" />
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton2"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton3"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton5"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton6"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="5"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton7"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton8"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton9"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:onClick="receiveClick"
                android:tag="8" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
01-04 18:20:49.903 7151-7161/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24719(987KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 80% free, 736KB/3MB, paused 48.882ms total 125.667ms
01-04 18:20:49.919 7151-7161/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.641ms
01-04 18:20:50.117 7151-7179/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-04 18:20:50.240 7151-7179/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 18:20:50.309 7151-7179/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 18:20:50.310 7151-7179/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad75f500, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-04 18:20:55.542 7151-7151/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 I/System.out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
01-04 18:20:55.542 7151-7151/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 18:20:55.543 7151-7151/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.richardcurteis.connect3, PID: 7151
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.andrInvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.Zygosupport.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.aiPlayerPick(MainActivity.java:71)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.playerClick(MainActivity.java:50)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.humanPlayerTurn(MainActivity.java:35)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.receiveClick(MainActivity.java:30)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```